# Having trouble figuring out my issue with Circle class

Tags: java, swing, geometry

I made another question about two weeks ago with having trouble with the Circle class. I couldn't exactly pinpoint a direct code to put on here to show you guys but no matter what I do with the Circle class, or any thing similar to it, I can't get the code to compile.

I have tried copying directly out of my textbook to see if the code provided by my teacher and the book will work, and I still get a "Cannot find symbol" whenever I try to create a Circle or Rectangle. Here's some code from my book for example

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Week8_ExtraCredit extends JApplet
{
    private int centerX = 200, centerY = 150;
    private Color toggleColor = Color.BLACK;
    private Circle circle;

    public void paint( Graphics g )
    {
        super.paint( g );

        for ( int diameter = 200; diameter >= 20; diameter -= 20 )
        {
            circle = new Circle( centerX - diameter / 2,
                                 centerY - diameter / 2,
                                 diameter, toggleColor );

            circle.draw( g );

            if ( toggleColor.equals( Color.BLACK ))
                toggleColor = Color.RED;
            else
                toggleColor = Color.BLACK;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is pulled directly from my book which is supposed to create a circle of with black and red rings inside of it. But running it, I get this error

```
C:\Users\yardeen\Documents\JCreator LE\MyProjects\Week8_ExtraCredit\src\Week8_ExtraCredit.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
    private Circle circle;
            ^
  symbol:   class Circle
  location: class Week8_ExtraCredit
```

This is given for every instance the class Circle is called upon. If I could get any help as to why I'm getting this problem, that would be awesome! This has been the only thing stumping me in learning Java so far. :\

Comment: Well, where is your `Circle` class?

Comment: Yeah, it would be helpful if you posted your actual Circle class.

Comment: Circle is not part of standard java (s2se), though Ellipse2D is. Assuming this class exists, you need to (A) add a jar file that contains the class to the classpath, and (B) add an import statement near the top of your class definition so you can use the class locally

Comment: Issue on line `private Circle circle;` - The compiler can not find class `Circle` - where do you have that? Do you have a `Circle.class` somewhere that you expect the compiler to see?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how to create a class. >.< I'm new to java, and this is the 8th week into a college course on working with it. We've yet to approach how to create a class, and this book never describes that I need to do such a thing. It lists those imports I've placed in this code, and then tells me how to instantiate a circle. Nothing more.

Comment: `Week8_ExtraCredit`  Please don't forget to add the [tag:homework] tag to homework questions. `JApplet`  Applets are not a good place to start.  They are harder than apps.  If that was your decision, I suggest changing it, if that was your teacher's decision, I suggest changing teachers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you didn't create a Circle class as your code and the above comments suggest, here's an alternate solution (unless you're required to create your own Circle class):

Make sure you have these imports:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
```

And then create an Ellipse:

```
Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, width, height);
```

This line will replace your "circle = new Circle" line. Make sure x, y, width, and height are doubles, and if you want further information check out [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.Double.html).

Comment: I'm sure this would work and thank you so much for the help. Unfortunately, I don't think this assignment will allow me to not use the Circle class.

Comment: Well I think you'll need to create your own class then. I'd be happy to help if your question provided more information, such as additional code, the assignment's text, etc.

Comment: There is no import that I'm leaving out that includes the Circle class? This seems oddly complex for a beginning java problem.

Comment: There is no Circle class in awt, unless there is a class material given to you that you haven't mentioned. You might want to double check the assignment or use my solution above if you don't want to create your own Circle class that will just use Ellipse2D anyway.

Comment: I figured out the issue! #1 messup I did was not make this in an applet project in the IDE. I also realized there was a circle class file provided in the textbook cd later on (which why they never mentioned in this in the bok itself, I'll never know.). That fixed everything up and I finally got to see what its like to animate something. :)